# htaccess protection for some subdomain folders only

Tags: hosting, .htaccess, subdomain

I have two site hosted as subdomains.

One of the site use subdomains as aliases for dynamic images requests.

```
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
sub1.example.com -> same as site1
sub2.example.com -> same as site1
sub3.example.com -> same as site1
```

Dynamic images are requested by `subX.example.com/images.php?`.

In the htaccess I want to:

- limit access to site1 and site2 (same user and password)
- have no authentication prompt on subXs
- redirect everything to images.php for subXs requests

**Limitations:**
I don't have access to httpd.conf so no directory block

I tested SetEnv, SetEnvIf, IfDefine with no success.

Comment: Are you saying that requests for: sub1.example.com/images.php? should be rewritten as site1.example.com/images.php?

Comment: No, for example sub1.example.com/index.php should be rewrittent as site1.example.com/images.php.  

A simple rewritte rule can do that (everything not images.php -> images.php) with a cond on the host.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the first 2 items, you need to use the `SetEnvIf` along with a `Satisfy`, something like this:

```
SetEnvIf Host site1.example.com need_auth
SetEnvIf Host site2.example.com need_auth

Order allow,deny

# setup whatever auth stuff you need here
AuthName "Private"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/pwd

# here's where you actually check the credentials and env
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!need_auth
Satisfy Any
```

To do the redirect, you can use mod_rewrite. I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but if you want *everything* redirected to images.php, you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:need_auth} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site1.example.com/images.php [R]
```

It would probably be a lot easier if you added a RedirectMatch in the vhost file for the subX.example.com domains. The .htaccess file is designed to be per-directory based configuration, and not host-based. It's not really designed to do the things you're asking.

Comment: I don't have access to the vhost too :(

Comment: I will test your solution, seems ok on paper ;)

Comment: Not ok. The satisfy any cancel the authentication prompt all the time. It seems the Allow from env=!need_auth does not work too. I tweaked it in every way i can think of, without luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It merit an A+ in weirdness.

In the root .htaccess :

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd # will be inherited by children directories .htaccess
```

An in site1 directory .htaccess :

```
SetEnvIf host ^s[0-9]+\. sub # Detect if the host target a subdomain for images

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Require valid-user

# Access to anything except image.php is forbidden on subdomains for images
<FilesMatch .*>
    Deny from env=sub
</FilesMatch>

# Access to image.php does not required authentication in subdomains for images
<Files image.php>
    Allow from env=sub
    Satisfy any
</Files>
```

And in site2 directory .htaccess :

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Require valid-user
```